# How to apply join based on parameter with linq

Tags: linq, join

I am using lambda expression to build a query and I got stuck in a situation where I have to apply join with 2 tables but it will be based on a parameter like if parameter "status=1" then join must be apply between 2 tables and if "status=0" then no join required to be apply there.

How it is possible to apply join based on some parameter?
Please remember I don't want to rewrite query 2 times with if and else conditions. I need to do this with single query.

Below is my query:

```
   db.Users.AsQueryable().AsExpandable().Where(featuredUserPredicate)
                     .GroupJoin(db.UserProfile, u => u.UserID, up => up.UserID, (u, up) => new { Users = u, UserProfile = up })
                     .SelectMany(s => s.UserProfile.DefaultIfEmpty().AsEnumerable(), (s, up) => new { s, up })


                    .GroupJoin(db.ProjectReview, u => u.s.Users.UserID, pr => pr.ReviewForUserId, (u, pr) => new
                     {
                         u,
                         pr

                     }).SelectMany(s => s.pr.DefaultIfEmpty().AsEnumerable(), (s, pr) => new
                     {

                         s.u,
                         Rate = pr == null ? 0 : pr.Rate

                     }).GroupBy(g => new { g.u.s.Users }).Select(r => new
                     {

                         key = r.Key.Users.UserID,
                         name = r.Key.Users,
                         sum = r.Sum(l => l.Rate)
                     }))
```

In above query I want to add one more join from "usercategory" table but this join will be based on "status" value. If value of "status=1" then join will apply otherwise this query will run as is.

Comment: *"I don't want to rewrite query 2 times with if and else conditions. I need to do this with single query."* Why?

Comment: because I have many parameters not a single parameter on which I have to apply join. I have "status" like many parameters. So I will have to write if else for all of them if I go for if else. I don't want to make it complex. If you have any simple solution so please suggest me. Thanks for quick reply.

Comment: You may try expression tree parsing to generate dynamic LINQ queries.

Comment: Can you show your query with join(s)?

Comment: Kaf, I edited my question and mentioned my query above please have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your query object like this.

```
var query = context.MyTable; //main query

query = status == 1 ? query.Join() : query; //apply join conditionally

query = query.Where()       // more expressions, might also need conditions here
query = query.Skip().Take() // apply your paging here
var result = query.ToList();// this is where the query will be executed.
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I can't use above options as  first line "var query = context.MyTable;" will get all records from DB but I dont want to get all record from one go. I only need 10 records in one go. So I have applied custom paging in my code. In this way if I get only 10 records and as per your code I will apply join after getting 10 records. This will be wrong. That's why I can't user this option

Comment: @VipinRathore - The first line will **not** get all of the records from the database. In fact, it doesn't get any. Linq uses a deferred execution model so no records will be returned until you execute the final query, and if you've filtered or paged the results then you'll only get the associated records.

Comment: @VipinRathore, please see the comment on the deferred execution. I've updated the code a bit to make it clear.

Comment: Thanks AD.Net to explain me the meaning of deferred execution process. Its really a helpful for me and finally I got my solution. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks to  Enigmativity also to help me to find out my solution.